# Automated video encoding linux

Tags: linux, video, encoding

I am looking for a program/utility which will automatically take whatever video file I give it and transcode it into another more suitable format for a web site.

Anyone know of a good linux (prefer ubuntu) utility?

Thanks,

-Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to learn mplayer ( it works best with ALL types of video ), first install acidrip from repos and get that working on the basics.

Once its going ok, use the Queue tab to be able to see the commands that are written. The commands are very long and this is the only place I have been able to see the FULL command with ease. This can then be fed into an automated tool.

The debug button in acidrip is also very handy to see what is going wrong when it does. Check your quality on playback as it can vary wildly depending on encoder, bitrate, etc...

have fun with it.

Answer (score 1):

HandBrake has a great CLI.  Without knowing what input files you are working with it's hard to say this will be suitable for you but it encodes to x.264 which is quite suitable for the web.

http://handbrake.fr

Comment: The problem is I have no idea what the input will be ... it could be literally anything ...

Answer (score 0):

`mencoder` can convert pretty much anything you can throw at it

it's usually inside the `mplayer` package

Answer (score 0):

**Prism Video Converter** can transcode quite a number of different formats.

http://www.nchsoftware.com/prism/index.html